# make similar css colorized box

Tags: css

I am trying to get The degree of color of the box in the picture

http://i46.tinypic.com/iefcpl.png

i like the box in the picture and i want make similar one

This is my code, and i can't make similarty

```
<style>
.b{
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ebebeb);
height:25px;
border:1px #efefef solid;
}
</style>

<div class="b">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.b{
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ebebeb)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ebebeb',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    height:25px;
    border:1px #DDDDDD solid;
}​
```

I used Ultimate [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate the gradient for all browsers.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/any6W/)

Comment: my question is to get the same degree of the color of the box in the picture, i already have this code, but i need the degree of color, the box in the picture is more lighter

Comment: In that case, it goes from `#FFFFFF` to `#F5F5F5`